# Error handling VBA index match

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, error-handling, match

I'm building a template to let the user to view and edit some values horizontally according to dates, and then update those values in another sheet where the data is vertically organized. I'm using index/match function to find the value, then checking if there's any changes.

After running this code, Column L is always #N/A. When I use index and match without VBA, some of the cell will be #N/A, because the date range is different and it cannot find a value. This is expected. If the lookUpvalue cannot be found or is the same as the original value, it should be kept the same, only making changes when value is found and different.

```
Public Sub TPHupdate()

Dim i As Double
Dim lookUpvalue As Variant
Dim lastRow As Double
Dim endRow As Double



lastRow = Worksheets("TPHPivot").UsedRange.Rows.Count
endRow = Worksheets("RoutingSpeed_MP").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To endRow
On Error Resume Next

lookUpvalue = Application.Index(Worksheets("TPHPivot").Range("E1001:P" & lastRow), Application.Match(Worksheets("TPHEdit").Range("B" & i), Worksheets("TPHPivot").Range("D1001:D" & lastRow), 0), Application.Match(Worksheets("TPHEdit").Range("F" & i), Worksheets("TPHPivot").Range("E1000:P1000"), 0))



If lookUpvalue = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
     Worksheets("RoutingSpeed_MP").Range("L" & i).Value = "#N/A"

ElseIf Worksheets("RoutingSpeed_MP").Range("G" & i).Value <> lookUpvalue Then
    Worksheets("RoutingSpeed_MP").Range("L" & i).Value = lookUpvalue

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: May want to debug the code while running and see what value is returned to lookUpValue.  If it is something other than "Error 2042" (#N/A), then your code may not catch it.  (Application.Index can also return #VALUE! if something else is wrong).  You also have a generic error catcher "On Error Resume Next" which may be masking a problem with your Range creations.  Might remove that and see if there is an Application Error you are missing currently.